# Fetching the entire elasticsearch document into a logstash event

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

How can I store the entire document found via the elasticsearch filter into the current logstash event? As far as I can tell, I can only target fields to be copied over manually by using the "fields" attribute of the ES filter. Moreover, I cannot exactly use the 'fields' attribute because I am querying across multiple indexes that have different shapes which may change in the future.

Ideally, my logstash event will have a new attribute 'results' or something of the like that contains a list of the documents that matched the query.

I would essentially like to do something like this:

```
filter {
  elasticsearch {
    query => "{memberGuid: %{[memberGuid]}"
    index => "members-*"
    fields => { "_document" => "results" }
    result_size => 1000
  }
}
```

I've tried using wildcard matching for the source fields, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tldr;

This is possible with the `docinfo_fields` that let you access the `_<fields>` of the query.

## Solution

```rb
filter {
  elasticsearch {
    query => "{memberGuid: %{[memberGuid]}"
    index => "members-*"
    docinfo_fields => { "_source" => "results" }
    result_size => 1000
  }
}
```